# Time.time vs DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond performance in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, performance, mono, unity-game-engine

I need to keep track of the time a lot in my multiplayer game built with Unity, in order to know when the packet of data came in. What would have better performance in Unity, Time.time or DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond? And by how much would the performance difference vary?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Uuuh...those two give values that mean different things. [`Time.time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html) gives you the time in seconds **since the start of the game**. Which is completely different from `DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond`, which gives you the system time in UTC. You probably want the latter.

Comment: @Serlite I think OP knows this. You can use both of them for a timer by subtracting them. I think OP wants to know which one is faster or recommended.

Comment: @Programmer It just seems logical to use the one more suitable for a timestamp, which is why I suspected the OP might be mistaken...(without doing extra math on the client side, the time since the game started isn't terribly useful for sorting data in a multiplayer game, since it'll vary for each player).

Comment: This question is for keeping track of timestamps on the client side only

Comment: It depends on how you use it. Can you post a code of how you are using it? When you say timestamp, you mean your game custom timestamp or system timestamp?

Comment: Have you tried to measure the performance of both methods using `Stopwatch`? Your question is so generic and so dependant on your implementation that only you can give a proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the best to test that by yourself. You're the one that knows your application best and can tell what is the most optimal solution in particluar conditions. This is some simple test script you can use. It just save current timestamp with unity/c# method and logs time needed for that operation.

```
public class TimeTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool UseUnityFuntion;

    private string msg;

    void Update ()
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        msg = UseUnityFuntion 
            ? Time.time.ToString() 
            : DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond.ToString();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (msg != null) GUILayout.Label(msg);
    }
}
```

Like in most cases, this time non-unity function seems to be faster. At least on my pc. Don't know how you're app would work, but keep in mind that you can have collisions when using Miliseconds value. 
There is also one disadvantage of using Time.time - you can do this only in main thread. When you have network application there is high chance you would like to save timestamp on background thread.

Answer (score 1):

For testing performance I would recommend:

- Not using ToString() within the profiled section
- Not using a branch that might favor on path over the other due to branch prediciton
- Repeating more than once if necessary to ensure that the resolution of the stopwatch is sufficient and that any potential variability in the cost of the stopwatch call is insignificant